# Rails 4 with CKEditor and legacy database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ms-word, ckeditor

I'm upgrading a website from Rails 2 to Rails 4, and am having problems with how Rails 4 wants to render the old CKEditor data.  All of my users are responsible for their own pages, and CKEdit let them format the text on their pages however they liked.

Rails 4 shows all that careful formatting as HTML tags.  I've gotten around that by directing all their code to a helper:

```
sanitize((value).gsub(/\\r\\n/, ' '), attributes: %w(style, class, etc., etc.))
```

So far so good.  But plenty of users formatted their text in MS Word and pasted into CKeditor.  Rails 4 displays this in all its MS-glory:

```
<!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"?? ??"; mso-font-charset:78; mso-generic-font-family:auto; .....
```

How do I show this formatting when I render the page?  It's tantalizing that CKEditor shows this formatting when editing, but Rails 4 won't in the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I could easily get the MS Word formatting to display was to use `raw(value)`.

I'm definitely not thrilled, but the only other option seems to be to discard all that user-formatting I spent so long encouraging.